mysql bulk insert with constraints
I created a table like this,
CREATE TABLE Leaderboard(
  userId bigint not null,              
  matchId bigint not null,
  score mediumint not null,
  country CHAR(10),
  tournamentId int not null
)

I am creating matches of 5 people, all from 5 distinct countries ("UK", "USA", "SPAIN", "GERMANY", "FRANCE)
I want to insert some a million entries to this table with following requirements,
A match will be formed like this
usergermany | userUSA | userSPAIN | userUK | userFrance 

so a match will have 5 users, all from distinct countries. A tournament will have many matches, and a user can only play in one match in a tournament.
So an example table will look like this
userid    matchid    score     country   tournamentid

...
988654    3877543    random    USA       177
388654    3877543    random    GERMANY   177
433432    3877543    random    FRANCE    177
776212    3877543    random    UK        177
1632987   3877543    random    SPAIN     177
2113242   3877544    random    SPAIN     177
2918974   3877544    random    USA       177
111738    3877544    random    UK        177
1772342   3877544    random    FRANCE    177
1343243   3877544    random    GERMANY   177
123131    3877545    random    UK        178
1231414   3877545    random    FRANCE    178
2858348   3877545    random    GERMANY   178
1122432   3877545    random    USA       178
2923434   3877545    random    SPAIN     178
...

A userId cannot exist in a tournament twice,
A country cannot exists in a match twice (match groups are formed from distinct countries)
Also since 5 players compete in a match, a matchid will only appear 5 times in the table.
I want to insert a million entries into this table, userid being randomly from 1 to 3 million with the above constraints. 10 thousand matches for each tournament, so there will be 100 tournaments starting from 1.
100 tournaments, 10000 matches each,  make up to 1 million rows.
--UPDATE--
create table seq_data as
with recursive tmp(x) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select x+1 from tmp
    limit 3000000
)
select * from tmp;
 
CREATE TABLE if not exists Leaderboard(
  userId bigint not null,
  matchId bigint not null,
  score mediumint not null,
  country CHAR(10),
  tournamentId int not null
);
 
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertLeaderboardData()
BEGIN
  DECLARE tournamentloop INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE matchloop INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE groupLoop INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE matchidKey INT DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE tournamentloop < 1 DO
    SET tournamentloop = tournamentloop + 1;
    SET matchloop = 0;
    WHILE matchloop < 10000 DO
      SET matchidKey = matchidKey + 1;
      SET matchloop = matchloop + 1;
      SET groupLoop = 0;
      WHILE groupLoop < 5 DO
       SET groupLoop = groupLoop + 1;
       INSERT INTO Leaderboard (userId, matchId, score, country, tournamentId)
       VALUES (1, matchidKey, FLOOR(RAND() * 1000) + 1, ELT(groupLoop, "SPAIN", "FRANCE", "UK", "USA", "GERMANY"), tournamentloop);
       SELECT matchidKey;
      END WHILE;
    END WHILE;
  END WHILE;
END;
//
 
DELIMITER ;
CALL InsertLeaderboardData();
DROP PROCEDURE InsertLeaderboardData;

This runs but slowly, yet I want 1 more feature.
As to INSERT INTO's userId I set the value to 1 for now to edit it later. What I want to do is, I created sequenced numbers into the table seq_data starting from 1 up to 3 million. For each WHILE tournamentloop < 100 DO scope, I want to get 50 thousand DISTINCT numbers from the seq_data table. so I can give the users an id.
The morale is, no userid can appear twice in a tournament. so for each tournament scope i need to retrieve random ids which are distinct and assign it to rows. I already created the table for sequenced numbers, I don't know what is the best approach from here.
-- Statement
INSERT INTO Leaderboard (userId, matchId, score, country, tournamentId) VALUES (useridKey, matchidKey, FLOOR(RAND() * 1000) + 1, ELT(groupLoop, "SPAIN", "FRANCE", "UK", "USA", "GERMANY"), tournamentloop);

I turn this into
DECLARE tournamentloop INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE matchloop INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE groupLoop INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE matchidKey INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE useridKey INT DEFAULT 1;
PREPARE insertStmt FROM 'INSERT INTO Leaderboard (userId, matchId, score, country, tournamentId)VALUES (useridKey, matchidKey, FLOOR(RAND() * 1000) + 1, ELT(groupLoop, "SPAIN", "FRANCE", "UK", "USA", "GERMANY"), tournamentloop);';
 EXECUTE insertStmt;

I get error: Unknown column 'useridKey' in 'field list'

Please study the difference between user-defined variables and local variables. And your task does not need in stored procedure, iterations and so on, needed dataset can be generated with single query which uses recursive CTE and statically generated  countries table.

WITH RECURSIVE must be written only once! all CTEs (both recursive and non-) are written after it before outer SELECT separated with a comma. Study Reference manual for correct syntax. Also you need only one CTE which generates a list of natural integers. Then you'd join needed amount of its copies in the outer query and use each copy for its personal purposes adding needed WHERE which restricts the amount of used numbers to needed one.

Where can we find the organizations documented rules for these tournaments and examples of how they think the participants will be managed.

I don't know. I just have a small workshop I am working on which I explained in the question. Yet I still couldn't achieve. I hope @Akina can help because this is a bit advanced for me.

@Akina please demonstrate how I can use the join with outer query for this purpose, I tried with while yet it is very very slow. Please please demonstrate, I really want to learn.

@Akina I want to avoid while loops, I know how to get natural list of integers with CTE but I really need a demo on how to use joins to form a table like above.

INSERT INTO Leaderboard (matchID, score, country, tournamentID)
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte1 (num) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT num + 1 FROM cte1 LIMIT 100 ),
cte2 (country) AS (SELECT "SPAIN" UNION ALL SELECT "FRANCE" UNION ALL SELECT "UK"
                   UNION ALL SELECT "USA" UNION ALL SELECT "GERMANY")
SELECT t1.num,           -- match ID
       RAND() * 100,     -- random score in 0..99
       t3.country,
       t2.num            -- tournament ID
FROM cte1 t1             -- match IDs
CROSS JOIN cte1 t2       -- tournament IDs
CROSS JOIN cte2 t3
WHERE t1.num <= 3        -- 3 matches per tournament
  AND t2.num < 5         -- 4 tournaments
;
-- totally the query creates 3 matches * 4 tournaments * 5 countries = 60 rows

fiddle

this is so great! indeed there is one last missing column, which is the userid, userid can be any number let's say between 1 to thousand but should be unique for every tournament id. (since a player can't play 2 matches at the same time in a tournament)

@umarkaa there is one last missing column, which is the userid See provided fiddle. userid is defined as autoincrement, so its values are filled automatically..

spasiva. Can you also try this, as I am studying the code... Not making it a PK but a random number between 0-50... but unique to each tournamentid... that is all,

@umarkaa Using cte1 and cte2, create cte3 which selects, for each country, some amount of randomly selected Ids (for example, join random country to each separate id, this will produce a rowset where there is no a userid value which belongs to more than one coutry). I.e. you'll obtain random amount of pairs (userid, country) for each country (check that those amount of pairs per country is not too small, maybe use dynamic country selection). In outer query you'd select one random pair for current country, with correlated subquery, for example.

@umarkaa a random number between 0-50... but unique to each tournamentid... Do you mean that the same userID may belong to different countries in different tournaments?

same userid will always belong to 1 country. but for demonstration purposes, it can be okay I guess. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78266539/sql-query-only-inserting-5-rows?noredirect=1#comment137981937_78266539" this answer of yours indeed i filled the user table with random values. So we could indeed use the User table

same userid will always belong to 1 country If so then create 100 users (use cte1), assign each user to definite country (use num MOD 5 as country index), insert random user with needed country into each table row.

I created 100 users, yet I am not sure how to use MOD with that. can you lastly help me with that this teaches me A LOT? CROSS JOIN cte1 tn WHERE t3.num = MOD 5 ?!

I am not sure how to use MOD with that Add id column to countries CTE with values from 0 to 4, and join by (cte3.num MOD 5 = cte2.id).

also @Akina, speaking from experience,  would CTE approach be faster than my so implemented WHILE loop structure? Also can you help me update the code (cte3.num MOD 5 = cte2.id)  sir ? :)

@umarkaa Your iterational code will parse your INSERT query on EACH iteration! At least use a prepared statement...

can you please edit this in a way that, userid is randomly assigned and unique to each tournament number, thank you... i already achieve with while loop I just want to see
